# Using SUM and MAX(date) in the same query

Tags: sql, database, google-sheets

I have a table that displays a dealer's name, the number of blocks they have outstanding and the last date an entry was made. It looks like this.

| Dealer | Blocks | Last Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dealer 1 | 10 | 09-Feb-23 |
| Dealer 2 | -5 | 24-Jan-23 |

The problem is that if the dealer has more than one entry in the master table where this data is being drawn from, my query does not display the Last Date. Here is the query I am currently using.

```
SELECT Dealer,
  SUM(CAST([Total Blocks] AS integer)), MAX(date) AS [Last Date]
FROM {{query1.data}}
WHERE Dealer = {{select1.value}}
OR {{select1.value == null}}
GROUP BY Dealer
ORDER BY Dealer
```

What do I need to change so that any dealers with multiple entries have the Last Date displayed?

I have searched the Internet for several days and have tried different changes to my query but nothing has worked.

Comment: Do you want the Last Date for that Dealer?  Or the Last Date for any Dealer?

Comment: what determines what the last _date is, when not the max of all dates for a dealer, maybe you need a CTE with a Row_number with the correct order and then select all that have rn 1

Comment: if you need only one dealer => WHERE Dealer = {{select1.value}} what is the meaning of ...  and ORRDER BY...

Comment: if you want the LAST date, use LAST(date), if need the MAX then use MAX(date)

Comment: What is the data type of your `date` field? It's possible you are looking for something like `MAX(TODATE(date))`

Comment: LAST(date) seemed to do the trick. I wasn't aware of that function, and it never came up in my searches. Thank you all for your help.